# Laravel can't access pivot additional column from pivot model itself

Tags: php, laravel, model, pivot, laravel-5.5

I have a pivot model called `UserTask` in which I have an accessor function:

```
class UserTask extends Pivot implements HasMedia
{
    use HasMediaTrait;

    public function getCompletedAttribute()
    {
        return $this->getMedia()->isEmpty() && $this->completed;
    }



    public function task()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Task::class);
    }

}
```

I specify the relation in my `Task` model like this:

```
class Task extends Model
{

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_task')->using('App\Models\UserTask')->withPivot('completed');
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> "message": "Undefined property: App\Models\UserTask::$completed",

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: where you see this error?!

Comment: It throws an exception. I am making an API call from postman.

Comment: what is your controller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this accessor function:

```
public function getCompletedAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->getMedia()->isEmpty() && $value;
}
```

Comment: This results with the following error: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::fromRawAttributes()`

Comment: Actually this works.. First it didn't work as I changed `extends Pivot` to `extends Model` just to test it and forgot to change it back. Weird but where does `$value` come from?

Comment: Works with `getCompletedAttribute($value)`?

Comment: From documentation: `The original value of the column is passed to the accessor, allowing you to manipulate and return the value.`

Comment: Can you send me a link to that documentation? took me ages to look for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165843/discussion-between-user3574492-and-vpalade).